# Replacing a variable name in text with the value of that variable

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a template that uses placeholders for the varying content that will be filled in. Suppose the template has:

```
"This article was written by AUTHOR, who is solely responsible for its content."
```

The author's name is stored in the variable `author`.

So I of course do:

```
wholeThing = wholeThing.replace('AUTHOR', author)
```

The problem is I have 10 of these self-named variables, and it would just be more economical if I could something like this, using only 4 for brevity:

```
def(self-replace):
    ...
    return

wholeThing = wholeThing.self-replace('AUTHOR', 'ADDR', 'PUBDATE', 'MF_LINK')
```

Comment: Aside from your function definition not being valid syntax, or named with a valid identifier, what have you tried? What flexibility do you have - could you change the template to use e.g. the `str.format` form? Use a dictionary mapping e.g. `{'AUTHOR': author, ...}`?

Comment: I didn't give a definition of the function. I just meant to indicate that the definition of such a function is what I'm looking for. As to what I've tried: repr(eval()) but that goes in the wrong direction. The dictionary may be the answer: I need to think about how it would work here.

Comment: You gave `def(self-replace):`, which is a very bad start in two different ways! But really two things are missing: *context*, what the limitations on your solution space are; and *effort*, what you actually tried to solve this problem and where you got stuck (give a [mcve]).

Comment: Oh! Whoops. I see what you mean. It should be def self-replace: No parens. I'm in favor of context and effort. :) But wasn't my example complete? In the sentence: "This article was written by AUTHOR, who is solely responsible for its content." (No quotes in the actual text of course) I want to replace the string AUTHOR with the content of author --and let's say that's Bob Jones. I am looking for a more unit-economical way than s = s.replace('AUTHOR', author)

Comment: That's still not a valid identifier and you definitely need parentheses.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a newbie. def sel-replace(variable-name):

Comment: *Both* "identifiers" there are syntax errors. I'd strongly recommend getting on top of the basics (see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and trying to do simple things well before trying to add a layer of abstraction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178024/discussion-between-harry-binswanger-and-jonrsharpe).

Answer (score 4):

With Python 3.6+, you may find formatted string literals ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)) efficient:

```
# data from @bohrax

d = {"publication": "article", "author": "Me"}
template = f"This {d['publication']} was written by {d['author']}, who is solely responsible for its content."

print(template)

This article was written by Me, who is solely responsible for its content.
```

Comment: Yes!!! This is the answer. And my lame attempts should not be adopted by anyone coming here. There are bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you need is string formatting, something like this:

```
def get_sentence(author,pud_date):
  return "This article was written by {}, who is solely responsible for its content. This article was published on {}.".format(author,pub_date)
```

Assuming you are parsing the variables that make up the string iteratively, you can call this function with the arguments needed and get the string returned.

That str.format() function can be placed anywhere and can take any number of arguments as long as there is a place for it in the string indicated by the {}. I suggest you play around with this function on the interpreter or ipython notebook to get familiar with it.

Comment: I will try thatt out, as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the templates I would use `str.format` and a `dict` containing the variables:

```
>>> template = "This {publication} was written by {author}, who is solely responsible for its content."
>>> variables = {"publication": "article", "author": "Me"}
template.format(**variables)
'This article was written by Me, who is solely responsible for its content.'
```

It is easy to extend this to a list of strings:

```
templates = [
    "String with {var1}",
    "String with {var2}",
]
variables = {
    "var1": "value for var1",
    "var2": "value for var2",
}
replaced = [template.format(**variables) for template in templates]
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems a little more elegant than what I worked out (which I'm posting as an answer)

Comment: I think I've really got it, but I can't post the code as code. The idea is to:
1. make a list of the placeholders, as literals, and 2. loop through the list doing replace(item, eval(item))

Comment: I think f-strings is easier if you have a bunch of different variables, like `author` and `publication`. If you have your "database" in a single dictionary `str.format` would make more sense.

Comment: Yes, f-strings are ideal. I've been using them successfully in a very taxing situation for a couple of weeks now.

Comment: ```template.format_map(variables)``` works faster